# Unknown A Record in dig results

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm very new to running my own webserver and have got a long way just reading, but i'm stuck now. I'm trying to point a subdomain to my own server and am coming up stuck.

I am hosting a static front end with netlify and have the followi[image]

when i run `dig api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk`

i am seeing

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk. 2631 IN   CNAME   18.216.122.25.
18.216.122.25.      0   IN  A   92.242.132.24
```

It looks to me like there is something pointing traffic away from my server but i have no idea what.

The registrar is reg-123 but i am using netlifiy's nameservers

If anyone has any idea where to look that would be great as i'm stumped

it looks like 92.242.132.24 is some sort of service that changes dns errors into advertising, so i'm not really sure what i do from here

thanks

--------edit----------

Okay so i removed the cname record as that was incorrect, now the output of dig is:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 64766
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk.  IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
candmelectricalltd.co.uk. 2987  IN  SOA dns1.p01.nsone.net. hostmaster.nsone.net. 1534273483 43200 7200 1209600 3600

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 194.168.4.100#53(194.168.4.100)
;; WHEN: Tue Aug 14 21:34:27 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 111
```

Comment: Remove that CNAME record and you'll be good. You can find all around the Internet documentation to understand what it is and how it works.

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie thanks for you help, i've removed that CNAME record but its still not working, i updated the question with the new dig response

Comment: @BenLonsdale Remove the A record, save, and then add it back in.

Comment: Thanks @Wesley i have done that now, just waiting on the TTL for the naked domain - will report back either later tonight or in the morning.... thanks again for your help

Comment: The target of a CNAME record should be a name, not an IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dig` will default to asking for an `A` record, so when you run `dig api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk` you get the `A` record answer, but to get to the ultimate `A` record, whoever last administered your domain has a `CNAME` record for `api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk` that has to be looked up next.

A `CNAME` says "Hey, I won't give you an IP address, I'm going to give you another human readable record to check next." Weirdly, the next record to check is `18.216.122.25`. That's an IP address, but a resolver is going to see it as hostname `18` and domain `216.122.25.` It'll query its own resolver, or root hints servers, for the `.25` TLD and fail. If that query has ever worked, I'm a bit puzzled and would like to see the *full* output of `dig api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk` including the `AUTHORITY SECTION` that you see. I suspect there's some strange hosts file trickery or DNS overriding going on close to your network.

I'm getting different results, and they make more sense (although you may have already deleted records by the time I queried):

```
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk.  IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
candmelectricalltd.co.uk. 900   IN  SOA dns1.p01.nsone.net. hostmaster.nsone.net. 1534273483 43200 7200 1209600 3600
```

Notice that there's no answer section and no `CNAME`.

## EDIT

The reason the remaining A records isn't showing up may be because your DNS host is lame. Remove the remaining A record, save the state, then re-add it and save the state.

Things are looking good now:

```
$ dig api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55260
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
api.candmelectricalltd.co.uk. 1139 IN   A   18.216.122.25

;; Query time: 10 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.11.1#53(192.168.11.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Aug 14 14:59:40 MST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 73
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, yeah so i changed the dns records and removed the cname as i realised that was wrong, see the comment under my question, i'm now seeing what you are seeing and am about to try and figure that one out

Comment: @BenLonsdale Things are looking good now. I think your DNS host is just lame.

Comment: RFC1123 says: *However, a valid host name can never
           have the dotted-decimal form #.#.#.#, since at least the
           highest-level component label will be alphabetic.*. A client should not use a string such as `192.0.2.37` as it were a domain name under the "TLD" `.37`. However the rule would not apply if you had `example.37` and indeed in the past an experiment was conducted with a ".42 REgistry" delivering domain names in the `.42` TLD.